# Change the drive-letter for multiple shortcuts

Tags: vb.net, shortcut, data-manipulation

I got a little problem. I got three backupdiscs for my computer and a sick ammount of windows-shortcuts.

My goal is to change the "target" and "open in" value for multiple windows-shortcuts (.ink) from:

"A:\Folder\File.mpg"

to

"D:\Folder\File.mpg"

for around 2k files.

I'm just blank on how to find (and change) the "target" and "open in" value within the windows-shortcuts (.ink). To be clear, it's only the partition letter, "A":\ in this case, I wish to change (to "D"), nothing else in the string. (for multiple items)

was thinking something like:

```
dim letterOne = combobox1.text
dim letterTwo = combobox2.text

    for each file
    shortcut.TargetPath("letterOne ", "*.ink")
```

**Change to**

```
shortcut.TargetPath("letterTwo", "*.ink")
```

Comment: Do you mean the text values in your code? Otherwise we have no idea what you mean by shortcuts. If they are the text values, use CTRL-h in visual studio to search and replace.

Comment: @DavidWilson thank you for the respond, figured out my original post was mostly confusing, so tried to clear up my request a bit :) Hope this is a more reasonable request :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am reading the question correctly, you can just use the `Replace` string function:

```
MyString.Replace("A:","D:")
```

If you need to do it for a lot of files, build a collection of the filenames and then use a `For Each` loop.